# How would I write a newline symbol to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write code to a python file from a python program

Example:

```
f.write("output.write(str(fib(int(line))) + '\n')")
```

I want the newline symbol to actually be written to the file and not place an actual newline in the file. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
... + '\\n'
```

Or use `r`aw strings:

```
... + r'\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding another backslash `\` before the newline symbol like so:

```
f.write("output.write(str(fib(int(line))) + '\\n')")
```